# Vector - number * vector =?

Tags: vectors, gram-schmidt

I can't wrap my head around these vector subtractions. They make 0 sense to me, can anyone help me get this simple step correct in my head? I'm getting nowhere since a hour.

Im trying to use the Gram-Schmidt on 3 vectors, but I can't get my head around the first equation of

$$u_2 = a_2 - \langle a_2,u_1 \rangle u_1$$

The final answer don't make any sense to me, I appended 2 pictures of 2 calculations that I just can't solve.

On the second equation I tried to multiply the $\frac12$ into the second vector and then tried to $v_1-v_2$, but it didn't get me the expected result.

Can anyone enlighten me this simple step?

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to mathematics stack exchange.  First do the scalar vector multiplication and then subtract

Comment: I don't know why i have been so blind, but i calculated it again and it works now - sorry for bothering you but also thanks for helping me! EDIT: Is there maybe an easier way to not multiply everything with 1/2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \left(
\begin{array}{cc|c}
  0\\
  1\\
1 \end{array}
\right) - \dfrac12 \left(
\begin{array}{cc|c}
  1\\0\\1
\end{array}
\right) =\left(
\begin{array}{cc|c}
  0\\
  1\\
1 \end{array}
\right) -  \left(
\begin{array}{cc|c}
  \frac{1}2\\0\\ \frac12
\end{array}
\right) =  \left(
\begin{array}{cc|c}
  \frac{-1}2\\1\\ \frac{1}2
\end{array}
\right)= \dfrac12\left(
\begin{array}{cc|c}
  {-1}\\2\\ {1}
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Another problem that came up: How can i normalize this to make it u2? I can't seem to the right result.

Comment: To normalize, divide by the magnitude, which is $\sqrt{\frac{-1}2^2+1^2+\frac12^2}=\frac {\sqrt6} 2$